# Add list to Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file like this (simplified):

```
  {'pageSize': 1,
   'vXPolicies': 
[
   {'columnType': 'Inclusion',
   'id': 123,

   'permMapList': [

    {'groupList': ['kor1'], 'permList': ['Select1'], 'userList': []},

    {'groupList': ['kor2'], 'permList': ['Select2'], 'userList': []}],

   'policyName': 'DB_policy',
    'version': '2'}]}
```

I want to add another list under "permMapList":

```
{'groupList': ['kor3'], 'permList': ['Select3'], 'userList': []}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append`:

```
your_dict['vXPolicies']['permMapList'].append(
    {'groupList': ['kor3'], 'permList': ['Select3'], 'userList': []})
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I just added the index [0] between ['vXPolicies'] and ['permMapList'] othervise I get an error. The command line is your_dict['vXPolicies'][0]['permMapList'].append(
    {'groupList': ['kor3'], 'permList': ['Select3'], 'userList': []})